# Bootstrap collapse jumps up instead of animating

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have element with Bootstrap collapse but sadly it is jumping up instead of just animating.

HTML:

```
    <section class="row faq-item">
        <h3 class="col-xs-11 col-md-10 faqalign" onclick="expand_faq(this);" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faq1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="faq1">
            Czy wystawiają państwo fakturę z odroczonym terminem płatności?
        </h3>
        <div class="collapse" id="faq1">
            <p class="col-xs-12">
                Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
 div.faq-list {
    border-top: 1px solid #d6dae3;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

.faq-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6dae3;
}

.faq-item p {
    margin-top: 9px;
}

 .faqalign {
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
 }

 .faq .icon-plus, .faq .icon-minus {
    font-size:20px;

 }

.faq .icon-plus::before, .faq .icon-minus::before{
    float: right;
}

.faq a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.faq h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Second version

Also I have code without wrapper - this animates in both directions, but have ugly jump at the end of hidding :/

HTML

```
    <section class="row faq-item">
        <h3 class="col-xs-11 col-md-10 faqalign" onclick="expand_faq(this);" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faq3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="faq3">Jaki jest czas realizacji zamówienia?</h3>

        <p class="col-xs-12 collapse" id="faq3">
            Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem upsumasdasdasd adas dasd asd  <a href="#">ipsum.</a>
        </p>

    </section>
```

CSS is the same.

Can someone help me figure out why it is not animating well?

Comment: Can't be onclick="expand_faq(this);" fault?

Comment: Moreover "You can use a link with the href attribute, or a button with the data-target attribute. In both cases, the data-toggle="collapse" is required."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because all the elements of your collapse content are all floated. This is happening due to the `col-xs-12` class on your `p` element. You can either remove that or set its `float` to `none`. Additionally, `margin` does not work well with Bootstrap's collapse either. A fix is to change it to `padding`.

```
.faq-item p {
    float: none;
    padding-top: 9px;
}
```

Live example here: http://www.bootply.com/XwYztUl4u5